# Regular Expression for Identifying keywords

Tags: python

I want to check whether the keywords are present or not in a text data,
The key words are,

```
Keywords=["just checking to see if you are there so we can continue.",
          "please let me know if you're receiving my responses or i will need to end our session", 
          "our chat session is now ending. thanks for choosing at&t!  we appreciate your business."]


Text= "Agent 'jl759s' enters chat (as Jacqueline)", "Hi Cristina!  My name is Jacqueline.  I'm happy to help.", 
  'Sure.', 
  'I see that you have issue with the internet service.', 
  "I'm sorry to hear that Cristina. Let me check that for you", 
  'Please not to worry, I can help you with that!', 
  'have you rebooted the router recently?', 
  'Thanks for the info!', 
  'Let me quickly run a line test to check if there is any issue detected either with the network lines or with the modem.',
  "You're welcome.",
  'Thank you for waiting Cristina.',
  'I wish I could resolve this issue through the chat session however it looks like this particular issue demands the expertise of the field technician.',
  'I understand that it is a little inconvenient to be waiting for a technician however we want to ensure that there is a permanent solution to this issue. I will do my best to get the earliest appointment available for you.',
  'I will dispatch a technician to the premise to help you on this.',
  'I am cehcking on the earliest available time slots now.',
  '*checking',
  'I see the earliest time slot available for the technician visit is on 10/16/2018 between 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM. Will it work for you?',
  'Ye sure.',
  'the technician will call you before the arrival.',
  'I will check that as well.',
  'The appointment is available on 10/20/2018.',
  'The available timings are 8:30 AM - 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM and 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM.',
  'Yes Cristina. Its available.',
  'Sure Cristina.',
  'Give me a minute.',
  'I have scheduled your appointment for October 16,
  xxxx. An AT&T technician will arrive as early as 4:00 PM or as late as 8:00 PM.',
  'Your service call may take 2-4 hours after arrival to resolve the issue.',
  'Please make sure all AT&T equipment is accessible to do repairs. Our technician will not move any furniture.',
  'An adult 18 years of age or older must be on-site for the duration of your Service Call and reachable on the day of the service call at 5863854186.',
  'With just two taps, you will able to track your repair/install appointment using the myAT&T app.',
  'Please launch the myAT&T app, input your member id and password, and then tap login. By tapping on the alert you will see all of your appointment details.',
  'Just to recap, You have reached us for the Internet service issue, as there is a line issue detected while troubleshooting I have dispatched a technician to help you fix this issue.',
  'I hope you do not have any concern with the assistance provided to you today. Is there anything else I can help you with I will be happy to assist?',
  'Pleasure is Mine Cristina!',
  'It was pleasure working with you!',
  'I appreciate your patience on this.',
  'Thank you for choosing AT&T. We appreciate your business. Have a great day!',
  'Bye!'
```

I have scripted the following code,

```
def Key_words(y):
    if(any(bool(re.search(r'\b'+x+r'\b', ''.join(y).lower()))) for x in keywords):
        return("Yes")
    else:
        return("No")

Key_words(Text)
```

Its giving the Output is `Yes`
But The output should be `No`, because there are no keywords are matching in the text.

Please help me to get the correct output.

Comment: Hi Srikanth, the `bool()` will evaluate to`True` for any non-empty list like object. See 'boolean context' in the Python docs

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `re.search`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

keywords=["just checking to see if you are there so we can continue.",  "please let me know if you're receiving my responses or i will need to end our session", "our chat session is now ending. thanks for choosing at&t!  we appreciate your business."]
Text= ["Agent 'jl759s' enters chat (as Jacqueline)", "Hi Cristina!  My name is Jacqueline.  I'm happy to help.", 'Sure.', 'I see that you have issue with the internet service.', "I'm sorry to hear that Cristina. Let me check that for you", 'Please not to worry, I can help you with that!', 'have you rebooted the router recently?', 'Thanks for the info!', 'Let me quickly run a line test to check if there is any issue detected either with the network lines or with the modem.', "You're welcome.", 'Thank you for waiting Cristina.', 'I wish I could resolve this issue through the chat session however it looks like this particular issue demands the expertise of the field technician.', 'I understand that it is a little inconvenient to be waiting for a technician however we want to ensure that there is a permanent solution to this issue. I will do my best to get the earliest appointment available for you.', 'I will dispatch a technician to the premise to help you on this.', 'I am cehcking on the earliest available time slots now.', '*checking', 'I see the earliest time slot available for the technician visit is on 10/16/2018 between 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM. Will it work for you?', 'Ye sure.', 'the technician will call you before the arrival.', 'I will check that as well.', 'The appointment is available on 10/20/2018.', 'The available timings are 8:30 AM - 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM and 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM.', 'Yes Cristina. Its available.', 'Sure Cristina.', 'Give me a minute.', 'I have scheduled your appointment for October 16, xxxx. An AT&T technician will arrive as early as 4:00 PM or as late as 8:00 PM.', 'Your service call may take 2-4 hours after arrival to resolve the issue.', 'Please make sure all AT&T equipment is accessible to do repairs. Our technician will not move any furniture.', 'An adult 18 years of age or older must be on-site for the duration of your Service Call and reachable on the day of the service call at 5863854186.', 'With just two taps, you will able to track your repair/install appointment using the myAT&T app.', 'Please launch the myAT&T app, input your member id and password, and then tap login. By tapping on the alert you will see all of your appointment details.', 'Just to recap, You have reached us for the Internet service issue,  as there is a line issue detected while troubleshooting I have dispatched a technician to help you fix this issue.', 'I hope you do not have any concern with the assistance provided to you today. Is there anything else I can help you with I will be happy to assist?', 'Pleasure is Mine Cristina!', 'It was pleasure working with you!', 'I appreciate your patience on this.', 'Thank you for choosing AT&T. We appreciate your business. Have a great day!', 'Bye!']


def Key_words(y):
    if re.search("(" +"|".join(keywords) + ")", r"\n".join(y), flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return("Yes")
    else:
        return("No")

print(Key_words(Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in` for it (faster and simpler):

```
keywords=["just checking to see if you are there so we can continue.",  "please let me know if you're receiving my responses or i will need to end our session", "our chat session is now ending. thanks for choosing at&t!  we appreciate your business."]
Text= ["Agent 'jl759s' enters chat (as Jacqueline)", "Hi Cristina!  My name is Jacqueline.  I'm happy to help.", 'Sure.', 'I see that you have issue with the internet service.', "I'm sorry to hear that Cristina. Let me check that for you", 'Please not to worry, I can help you with that!', 'have you rebooted the router recently?', 'Thanks for the info!', 'Let me quickly run a line test to check if there is any issue detected either with the network lines or with the modem.', "You're welcome.", 'Thank you for waiting Cristina.', 'I wish I could resolve this issue through the chat session however it looks like this particular issue demands the expertise of the field technician.', 'I understand that it is a little inconvenient to be waiting for a technician however we want to ensure that there is a permanent solution to this issue. I will do my best to get the earliest appointment available for you.', 'I will dispatch a technician to the premise to help you on this.', 'I am cehcking on the earliest available time slots now.', '*checking', 'I see the earliest time slot available for the technician visit is on 10/16/2018 between 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM. Will it work for you?', 'Ye sure.', 'the technician will call you before the arrival.', 'I will check that as well.', 'The appointment is available on 10/20/2018.', 'The available timings are 8:30 AM - 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM and 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM.', 'Yes Cristina. Its available.', 'Sure Cristina.', 'Give me a minute.', 'I have scheduled your appointment for October 16, xxxx. An AT&T technician will arrive as early as 4:00 PM or as late as 8:00 PM.', 'Your service call may take 2-4 hours after arrival to resolve the issue.', 'Please make sure all AT&T equipment is accessible to do repairs. Our technician will not move any furniture.', 'An adult 18 years of age or older must be on-site for the duration of your Service Call and reachable on the day of the service call at 5863854186.', 'With just two taps, you will able to track your repair/install appointment using the myAT&T app.', 'Please launch the myAT&T app, input your member id and password, and then tap login. By tapping on the alert you will see all of your appointment details.', 'Just to recap, You have reached us for the Internet service issue,  as there is a line issue detected while troubleshooting I have dispatched a technician to help you fix this issue.', 'I hope you do not have any concern with the assistance provided to you today. Is there anything else I can help you with I will be happy to assist?', 'Pleasure is Mine Cristina!', 'It was pleasure working with you!', 'I appreciate your patience on this.', 'Thank you for choosing AT&T. We appreciate your business. Have a great day!', 'Bye!']


def Key_words(y):
    text = ' '.join(y).lower()
    print(text)
    for key in keywords:
        if key.lower() in text:
            return("Yes")
    return("No")


print(Key_words(Text))
```

Here we will iterate each keyword only in the situation where no one keyword in the text. In all other situations, we will have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do something simple like this:

```
Keywords=["just checking to see if you are there so we can continue.",  "please let me know if you're receiving my responses or i will need to end our session", "our chat session is now ending. thanks for choosing at&t!  we appreciate your business."]
Text= "Agent 'jl759s' enters chat (as Jacqueline)", "Hi Cristina!  My name is Jacqueline.  I'm happy to help.", 'Sure.', 'I see that you have issue with the internet service.', "I'm sorry to hear that Cristina. Let me check that for you", 'Please not to worry, I can help you with that!', 'have you rebooted the router recently?', 'Thanks for the info!', 'Let me quickly run a line test to check if there is any issue detected either with the network lines or with the modem.', "You're welcome.", 'Thank you for waiting Cristina.', 'I wish I could resolve this issue through the chat session however it looks like this particular issue demands the expertise of the field technician.', 'I understand that it is a little inconvenient to be waiting for a technician however we want to ensure that there is a permanent solution to this issue. I will do my best to get the earliest appointment available for you.', 'I will dispatch a technician to the premise to help you on this.', 'I am cehcking on the earliest available time slots now.', '*checking', 'I see the earliest time slot available for the technician visit is on 10/16/2018 between 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM. Will it work for you?', 'Ye sure.', 'the technician will call you before the arrival.', 'I will check that as well.', 'The appointment is available on 10/20/2018.', 'The available timings are 8:30 AM - 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM and 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM.', 'Yes Cristina. Its available.', 'Sure Cristina.', 'Give me a minute.', 'I have scheduled your appointment for October 16, xxxx. An AT&T technician will arrive as early as 4:00 PM or as late as 8:00 PM.', 'Your service call may take 2-4 hours after arrival to resolve the issue.', 'Please make sure all AT&T equipment is accessible to do repairs. Our technician will not move any furniture.', 'An adult 18 years of age or older must be on-site for the duration of your Service Call and reachable on the day of the service call at 5863854186.', 'With just two taps, you will able to track your repair/install appointment using the myAT&T app.', 'Please launch the myAT&T app, input your member id and password, and then tap login. By tapping on the alert you will see all of your appointment details.', 'Just to recap, You have reached us for the Internet service issue,  as there is a line issue detected while troubleshooting I have dispatched a technician to help you fix this issue.', 'I hope you do not have any concern with the assistance provided to you today. Is there anything else I can help you with I will be happy to assist?', 'Pleasure is Mine Cristina!', 'It was pleasure working with you!', 'I appreciate your patience on this.', 'Thank you for choosing AT&T. We appreciate your business. Have a great day!', 'Bye!'

for k in Keywords:
    if k in Text:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is a misplaced parenthesis on this line:

```
if (any(bool(re.search(r'\b'+x+r'\b', ''.join(y).lower()))) for x in keywords):
```

In your case, the expression `re.search(r'\b'+x+r'\b', ''.join(y).lower())` always evaluates to `None`, so the above `if` statement can be rewritten to:

```
if (any(bool(None)) for x in keywords):
```

Now, the expression `(any(bool(None)) for x in keywords)` returns a generator which, for each `x` in `keywords`, yields the expression `any(bool(None))`. The expression itself is not semantically valid because `any` requires an iterable, not `bool`, as its argument, so this would raise a `TypeError` by itself.

The expression `any(bool(None))`, however, is never being evaluated because it is not needed. The `if` statement immediately succeeds because its argument is a generator (not a `bool`) and generators always evaluate to `True` when converted to `bool`, no matter what they generate.

So, to fix the behaviour, you need to move the parentheses like this:

```
if any(bool(re.search(r'\b'+x+r'\b', ''.join(y).lower())) for x in keywords):
```